# Ionic google maps not loading view with firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

My ionic 1 project currently has firebase authentication which lets the user log in with an email and password and redirects the user to view that can only be accessed when the user is logged in.

I want to load google maps on the logged in view. I have successfully been able to load google maps on another view that does not firebase authentication in its controller but the minute I put the same code in the controller of the logged in view and setup the div with on the logged in view then it does not load up. There have been no errors in console so im not quite sure what is going on.

So code is as followed:
AuthService calls the firebase service

MuserController (Controller of logged in view):

```
.controller('MuserCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $state, AuthService, $cordovaGeolocation) {
    $scope.$parent.clearFabs();
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
    }, 0);


    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();


    $scope.current_user = {};

    var current_user = AuthService.getUser();


    //if user is already logged in
    if(current_user) {

        //If facebook login
        if (current_user && current_user.provider == "facebook") {
            $scope.current_user.email = current_user.facebook.displayName;
            $scope.current_user.image = current_user.facebook.profileImageURL;
        }

        //If email login
        else {

            /*Google Map setting*/
            var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: latLng,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            }, function(error){
                console.log("Could not get location");
            });



            $scope.current_user.email = current_user.password.email;
            $scope.current_user.image = current_user.password.profileImageURL;
        }

    //No user is currently logged in
    } else {
       $state.go('app.start');
    }


    //Logout Function
    $scope.logout = function(){
        AuthService.doLogout();

        $state.go('app.start');
    };

})
```

Services.js (Firebase Authentication Service):

```
angular.module('socialAuth',[])
.service('AuthService', function($q){
    var _firebase = new Firebase("https://logfirebase.firebaseio.com/");
    // var _firebase = new Firebase("https://geomuse-169214.firebaseio.com");
    // var config = {
    //     apiKey: "AIzaSyBwdvuilAWOU9DttaGPabpKsHIDHJOuF1Q",
    //     authDomain: "geomuse-169214.firebaseapp.com",
    //     databaseURL: "https://geomuse-169214.firebaseio.com",
    //     projectId: "geomuse-169214",
    //     storageBucket: "geomuse-169214.appspot.com",
    //     messagingSenderId: "103764525324"
    // };
    // firebase.initializeApp(config);
    // var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

    this.userIsLoggedIn = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            authService = this,
            isLoggedIn = (authService.getUser() !== null);

        deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.getUser = function(){
        return _firebase.getAuth();
    };

    this.doLogin = function(user){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        _firebase.authWithPassword({
            email    : user.email,
            password : user.password
        }, function(errors, data) {
            if (errors) {
                var errors_list = [],
                    error = {
                        code: errors.code,
                        msg: errors.message
                    };
                errors_list.push(error);
                deferred.reject(errors_list);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.doFacebookLogin = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        _firebase.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(errors, data) {
            if (errors) {
                var errors_list = [],
                    error = {
                        code: errors.code,
                        msg: errors.message
                    };
                errors_list.push(error);
                deferred.reject(errors_list);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.doSignup = function(user){
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            authService = this;

        _firebase.createUser({
            firstname    : user.firstname,
            lastname    : user.lastname,
            email    : user.email,
            password : user.password,
            gender : user.gender
        }, function(errors, data) {
            if (errors) {
                var errors_list = [],
                    error = {
                        code: errors.code,
                        msg: errors.message
                    };
                errors_list.push(error);
                deferred.reject(errors_list);
            } else {
                // After signup we should automatically login the user
                authService.doLogin(user)
                    .then(function(data){
                        // success
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    },function(err){
                        // error
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    });
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.doLogout = function(){
        _firebase.unauth();
    };
})
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ion-md-input/css/ion-md-input.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/geomuse.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ion-md-input/js/ion-md-input.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!--Googple maps plugin-->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAq9weEMgdVahLcdbvokguOZDuZ3PVVyig&sensor=true"></script>

    <!--Firebase-->
    <script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js"></script>


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

muser.html (Logged in view):

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" align-title="left">
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ionic-material', 'ionMdInput', 'ngCordova', 'firebase', 'socialAuth'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state, AuthService, $rootScope) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        AuthService.userIsLoggedIn().then(function(response)
        {
            if(response === true)
            {
                $state.go('app.muser');
            }
            else
            {
                $state.go('auth.connect');
            }
        });

        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });

    // UI Router Authentication Check
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if (toState.data.authenticate)
        {
            AuthService.userIsLoggedIn().then(function(response)
            {
                if(response === false)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('auth.connect');
                }
            });
        }
    });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    // Turn off caching for demo simplicity's sake
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);

    /*
    // Turn off back button text
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false);
    */

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.activity', {
        url: '/activity',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/activity.html',
                controller: 'ActivityCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: '<button id="fab-activity" class="button button-fab button-fab-top-right expanded button-energized-900 flap"><i class="icon ion-paper-airplane"></i></button>',
                controller: function ($timeout) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        document.getElementById('fab-activity').classList.toggle('on');
                    }, 200);
                }
            }
        }
    })


    .state('app.register', {
        url: '/register',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
                controller: 'ConnectCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            authenticate: false
        }
    })


    .state('app.register-email', {
        url: '/register-email',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/register-email.html',
                controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            authenticate: false
        }
    })

    .state('app.login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller: 'ConnectCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            authenticate: false
        }
    })

    .state('app.forget-password', {
        url: '/forget-password',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/forget-password.html',
                controller: 'ForgetPasswordCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/auth/sign-up.html',
                controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            authenticate: false
        }
    })

    .state('app.connect', {
        url: '/connect',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/auth/connect.html',
                controller: 'ConnectCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            authenticate: false
        }
    })


    .state('app.muser', {
        url: '/muser',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/app/muser.html',
                controller: 'MuserCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            authenticate: false
        }
    })
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/start');
});
```

Help would be greatly appreciated